# phpmyadmin shows up error when clicking into browse in the table

Tags: phpmyadmin, ubuntu-14.04

Hi i have this project and i runs this on ubuntu OS. Im using zend framework 1.12.7, I have this register page and it should be saved on the users table. What ive noticed is when i click on the users table in the "browse" to check if the data is succesfully saved this is what it goes

```
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0df3bbfgd2
```

It shows some error. I dont know what did i done wrong. Can someone help me solved this problem? It showed up after when i tried to register on the page. Any help is muchly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You have enabled to store the UI preferences but have not created the required table.
You have two options, either of two should work:

1. **Create the phpMyAdmin storage database and tables**: For this all you have to do is import the create_tables.sql from the example folder of phpMyAdmin source.
2. **Disable the UI preferences storage capability**: For this you just have to comment the line `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';` from config.inc.php.

I would recommend to opt for option 1 to have better use of phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the UI preferences storage capability